# Disable black background color of a satellite image in mapserver mapfile?

Tags: raster, mapserver, mapfile, image-service, background-geoprocessing

I'm publishing rasters using Mapserver. How to disable background color of a satellite image in map files or How to set “Display Background value ”0“?

Comment: this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653607/how-do-you-get-transparent-background-in-a-layer-with-umn-mapserver

Comment: Documentation could also help. Read http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html?highlight=offsite%20raster. Adding OFFSITE 0 0 0 into your layer should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MapServer the pixel value of a raster layer that should be interpreted as "nodata" and which should therefore be transparent is defined in the LAYER section of mapfile with the OFFSITE parameter. This is explained in MapServer documention at http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html?highlight=offsite%20raster.